# How to make a button with an icon on the side bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The question is simple, i have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 20%; color: white">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">
          <h5>
              <strong>Añadir sucursal</strong>
          </h5>
     </i>
</button>
```

From this:

[image]

To something like this:

[image]

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to customize this code only? Because you can easily do this by following the  bootstrap button example: <button class="btn btn-warning">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"> </i>  Añadir sucursal
</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 20%; color: white">
    <h5><strong>Añadir sucursal</strong> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></h5>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The button text is below the icon because it is in an `<h5>` tag, and the `<h5>` is a block element.

If you want to use the styling of `<h5>` but keep it on the same line, add the `d-inline` class to the h5 tag, which will change it into an inline element:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/fontawesome.min.css">

<body class="p-4">
  <p>Original button with &lt;h5&gt;</p>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 20%; color: white">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">
          <h5>
              <strong>Añadir sucursal</strong>
          </h5>
     </i>
</button>

  <p class="mt-4">Button with &lt;h5 class="d-inline"&gt;:</p>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" style="width: 13rem; color: white">
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle">
          <h5 class="d-inline">
              <strong>Añadir sucursal</strong>
          </h5>
     </i>
</button>
</body>
```